# Displaying several pictures with Content Editor Web Part

Tags: 2013, javascript, web-part, script

I've created a script editor on my new sharepoint 2013 Version on the left side of the sharepoint site, like this:

- Test 1
- Test 2
- Test 3

I would like that by clicking on each Test line (Test 1, Test 2, Test 3,)the corresponding pictures (which I've already saved in the picture library) will appear on the right sight in a Content Editor Web Part. 
I am looking for a suitable script.
Right now, I can only display the pictures in a new window. Is there maybe a better script which opens the pictures in the content Editor web part and changes the pics. automatically when clicking Test 2 and Test 3?

Thanks in advance